# Как удалить нечитаемые символы из строки?

Tags: c#

Есть переменная. В режиме отладки в нём такое значение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А в режиме просмотра значения вот такое. Как удалять из строки "нечитаемые" символы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уточните, какие символы вы считаете нечитаемыми? И куда идет их вывод? Покажите код. )

Comment: @Kromster квадратик в конце

Comment: Под вопросом кнопка "править", используйте ее )

Comment: `string text = tab0.Trim('\a')`

Comment: @aepot спасибо кэп)

Comment: Определите для себя, какие символы вы считаете нечитаемыми: [UnicodeCategory Enum](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.unicodecategory?view=netcore-3.1), [Supported Unicode general categories](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#SupportedUnicodeGeneralCategories) [Supported named blocks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#SupportedNamedBlocks).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov всё что образует "квадратики" в режиме просмотра

Comment: @Radzhab то, что образует квадратики в режиме просмотра зависит ОТ ШРИФТА используемого при просмотре. Например, кирилические буквы на большинстве латинных шрифтах так же будут отображатся квадратиками, хотя ты вряд ли считаешь что это нечитаемые символы. Я советую прислушатся к коментарию Alexander Petrov и ему последовать.

Comment: У меня вопрос: как и откуда вы получили эти данные? Есть предположение, что нормальный видимый символ разорван пополам при неправильном получении данных, например, по сети, когда поток байтов не дочитывается до конца и уже передаётся на обработку.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov его я получил из Word файла

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нечитаемых символов в юникоде много. И они относятся к разным категориям: [UnicodeCategory Enum](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.unicodecategory?view=netcore-3.1), [Supported Unicode general categories](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#SupportedUnicodeGeneralCategories), [Supported named blocks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#SupportedNamedBlocks).

Убрать их можно либо методами работы со строками, либо регулярками.

Нужно определиться с тем, какие категории отфильтровывать. Допустим, уберём все символы, которые относятся к контрольным (перевод каретки, табуляция и т. п.)

```
string input = "E\a";
Console.WriteLine(input.Length); // 2

string output = new string(input.Where(c => !char.IsControl(c)).ToArray());                        
Console.WriteLine(output.Length); // 1
```